# Multiple foreach loops with arrays inside of an array

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
$array = array(
   'val1' => array('en'=>'Option Title 1','a'=>1),
   'val2' => array('en'=>'Option Title 2','b'=>2),
   'val3' => array('en'=>'Option Title 3','c'=>3)
);
```

I tried running this code to generate a select box :

```
function setOptions($array){
    echo '<select name="select">';
    foreach($array as $key_parent => $val_parent){
        foreach($val_parent as $key => $val){
            if($key !== 'en'){
                $option_value = $val;
            }elseif($key == 'en'){
                $option_title = $val;
            }
        }
        echo '<option value"'.$option_value.'">'.$option_title.'</option>';
    }
    echo '<select>';
}
```

This prints what I expected.

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="1">Option Title 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option Title 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option Title 3</option>
</select>
```

However when I print the return value of `$_POST['select']` from a form submission, I get `Option Title 1`, `Option Title 2`, or `Option Title 3`, not `1,2 or 3` which I thought was pretty odd.

So this leaves the question, how do I get the values inside of val1, val2, val3 when the key of one of the values in question is unknown(either a,b or c)?

Comment: How is your form being posted? Via AJAX? If so, show us the javascript that handles this.

Comment: Have you tried <select name="select[]"> and accessing the result accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss equal in value attribute.

```
function setOptions($array){
    echo '<select name="select">';
    foreach($array as $key_parent => $val_parent){
        foreach($val_parent as $key => $val){
            if($key !== 'en'){
                $option_value = $val;
            }elseif($key == 'en'){
                $option_title = $val;
            }
        }
        echo '<option value="'.$option_value.'">'.$option_title.'</option>';
    }
    echo '<select>';
}
```